# node.js - .then() is not defined

Tags: node.js

I'm using node.js + Express + sequelize for my API.
I have a post method where I use bulkcreate (to insert several rows at the same time to a table) but it makes an error: then is not defined.

This is my error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>`enter code here`
</head>
<body>
<pre>ReferenceError: then is not defined<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at router.post (C:\Users\Desktop\PROYECTOS\viajeros-api\routes\travellers.js:143:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Desktop\PROYECTOS\viajeros
....
</body>
</html>
```

This is my post method:

```
router.post('/:id/countries', (req, res) => {

  const travellerId = req.params.id;
  const registerJson = req.body;
    for(let i = 0; i < registerJson.length; i++) {
          models.travellers_countrie.bulkCreate([
            { traveller_id:travellerId, country_id:registerJson[i].id }
            ])
        };
    then(() => { 
      return models.travellers_countrie.findAll();
    }).then(paises => {
      console.log(paises)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('estamos en el error');
      console.log(error);
      let response = Errors.errorResponse(error);
      res.status(500).send(response);
    });
});
```

I can't solve the problem. Any idea to find the solution? thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to insert a list of countries to a table (travellers_countries). This insertion works fine but always throws an error (then is not defined).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bulk edit then you should format data first, then update. Using database operation in for loop is not good practice in your code

Also, you are referring `.then` outside the for loop and your bulk insert function that's why its giving error.

Refer to this code, it should work now

```
const dataArray = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < registerJson.length; i++) {
    dataArray.push({ traveller_id:travellerId, country_id:registerJson[i].id })          
  };

 models.travellers_countrie.bulkCreate(dataArray)
    .then(() => { 
      return models.travellers_countrie.findAll();
    }).then(paises => {
      console.log(paises)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('estamos en el error');
      console.log(error);
      let response = Errors.errorResponse(error);
      res.status(500).send(response);
    });
```